# Are saltwater-rated reels more dirtproof?

Tags: fishing

I get so much grit in my spinning reels. I try not to drop them in the mud/dirt/gravel that dominates the creeks and rivers where I fish, but it's often unavoidable in the rush to unhook and release a fish, or when I slip in the snot-slick Maryland mud. As a result, there's grit in the bail and gears of both my favorite reels.

You always hear that saltwater reels are built to keep water out of their innards, but I have zero experience with them because I stick to freshwater. If I were to switch to a saltwater-rated reel such as the Kastking Kodiak, would it at least help keep the gear mechanisms grit-free? Is there a better solution, other than just "don't be so bad at fishing, you dingus"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After fishing I always wash my reels down with fresh water to get rid of grit. Also have you tried lubricating your reels more often, this could help too. I love using Shimano spinners and have had no problem with grit, that could be an option too.

Answer (score 2):

It would also depend on the IPX rating that some reels have, however this is usually just for the bearings and some of the internal gears that can rust on salt water reels-ideally you’d want to keep dust/dirt off of a reel, and then lightly mist or hose off then spray with Inox or something similar.